# validation script ReferenceError

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, validation

I got the following error some time on my website and after refreshing the page its work fine...

> with the validation script ReferenceError: validateOptionsCallback is not defined at eval (eval at updateCallback (website.com/js/prototype/validation.js), :1:1) at Function.updateCallback (https://website.com/js/prototype/validation.js:245:13) at Function.test (https://website.com/js/prototype/validation.js:304:18) at eval (https://website.com/js/prototype/validation.js:177:35) at eval (https://website.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:845:37) at eval (https://website.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:825:18) at Array.forEach () at Array.each (https://website.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:824:12) at Array.all (https://website.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:844:10) at Function.validate (https://website.com/js/prototype/validation.js:176:28)

would someone guide me what's wrong or how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is this happening frequently in all browsers?

Comment: It happens from time to time .. no special case where it happens